# Module missing when trying to create local REPL for Clojure project

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

Hi am trying to create a local REPL for a Clojure project in IntelliJ Ultimate 2018.1.6.

Run/debug configurations > Edit configurations > Add Clojure REPL > Local

Under common options the module dropdown list does not contain any modules

[image: Run configurations]

I am not sure how to add the project module to the list. I am new to Clojure, IntelliJ and the entire ecosystem so I am trying to wrap my head around all this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to open your `project.clj`.

A hint shall appear, saying, Leiningen project is not registered.

[image]

Press `Add project` and after that proceed to your `Run/debug configurations > Edit configurations > Add Clojure REPL > Local`

Comment: Do you know why that happened? I think it was either because I opened the project without importing it or I imported it without selecting the module. What did you do to replicate this? And thank you so much.